# Porting asp website from iis6 to iis7 windows 2008

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic

I moved iis website from windows 2003 iis6 to 2008 iis 7. For some reason this asp code stopped working. I enabled trace and this is what I get:

> ErrorCode 800a000d  Description Type mismatch.

I get it on `If broj > 0 Then` line. Is this because of classic asp not working on IIS7 ?

```
 <%
      Dim cate, SQL, broj
      cate = Request("cate")


      SQL = "select count(*) as count from members where category_id = '" & cate & "' and status_flag <> 'NON-MEMBER' and status = 'APPROVED' order by company;"
      rs.Open SQL,Con,adOpenKeyset,adLockOptimistic
     broj = rs("count")


      If broj > 0 Then   // <-- this is the line where i get error ErrorCode 800a000d Description Type mismatch//

         rs.close
         rs.PageSize = 3
         rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient

         SQL = "select * from members where category_id = '" & cate & "' and status_flag <> 'NON-MEMBER' and status = 'APPROVED' order by company;"
         rs.Open SQL,Con

         datum = MonthName(Month(rs("last_updated"))) & " " & Day(rs("last_updated")) & ", " & Year(rs("last_updated"))

      %>
```

Comment: have you tried 'if cint(broj) > 0'

Comment: You are wide open to SQL injection with that code, you might want to clean it up, even if it is internal.

John's answer above is correct, the data for whatever reason seems to be coming back as a string and not an int.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a checklist I put together while moving a bunch of Classic ASP sites from IIS 6 to 7:

(1) Do not name site folders with .com at the end.

(2) Create user account:
- [app pool user identity] is app_pool_blahblahblah, pw: xxxxxx

(3) In Server Manager, right click "Web Server (IIS)" and choose "Add Role Services". Add IIS 6 Management Compatibility.

(4) In Server Manager under features add SMTP server.
Install IIS6 Resource Kit so you can 
Use Metabase Explorer.
Grant the [app pool user identity] user read access to the /Local Machine/SmtpSvc/ and /Local Machine/SmtpSvc/1/ nodes in the IIS Metabas

(5) In Application Pool, advanced settings:
- set .Net Framework version to "v2.0" <-- fixed issue with default asp doc not working!
- set "Enable 32-bit applications" to TRUE.
- set managed pipeline mode to "Classic".
- under Process Model, change Identity to "[app pool user identity]" account we created.
- be sure "load user profile" is set to FALSE.
- be sure "maximum worker processes" is "1".

(6) Mail: In IIS 6 Management Console:
http://intellitect.com/configuring-windows-smtp-server-on-windows-2008-for-relay/
- Under SMTP Virtual Server Properties:
    -- "Access" Tab --> Relay: add IPs of this box, including 127.0.0.1
    -- "Delivery" Tab --> Advanced: for "fully qualified domain name" put name of box
    -- "Delivery" Tab --> Advanced: for "smart host" put "dedrelay.secureserver.net"
    -- "Delivery" Tab --> Outbound connections: Make sure limits are set to 100.
    -- "Security" Tab --> add "[app pool user identity]" and IIS_IUSRS

(7) In IIS 7.5 under web site:
- Under ASP:
    -- ONLY IF PROBLEM: set enable buffering to "false"
    -- under limits change max req entity and buffering limit to 1024000000
    -- set script language to "vbscript"
    -- set "send errors to browser" to true
- Authentication --> edit "Anonymous Authentication" and set to app pool identity.
- ONLY IF PROBLEM: under error pages: under 404 set to "/home.asp" and "execute URL"
- ONLY IF PROBLEM: edit c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config: change  to "Allow"
- under Management (at bottom) go into "Configuration Editor".
    -- In the dropdown go to System.web --> http runtime and change maxRequestLength to 1024000000
    -- In the dropdown go to System.webserver/security/requestFiltering --> chg allowDoubleEscaping=true

(8) 
Set "Modify" Permissions for the following folders: 
- windows\temp
- inetpub\temp
- inetpub\mailroot
- ONLY IF PROBLEM: windows\serviceprofiles\networkservice\AppData\Local\Temp?

AND Set Permissions in registry:
- ONLY IF PROBLEM: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines?

FOR THESE USER ACCOUNTS:
- IIS_IUSRS
- [app pool user identity]
- NETWORK SERVICE

(9) Install and Use Process Monitor to find permissions issues - filter